# KSOAP2 can send complex type but can't receive it back

Tags: web-services, java-me, ksoap2, java1.4

I'm working on a project that needs to access a 3rd party dotNet WebService.

I'm using ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar (Java 1.4 compatible).
I can't use java > 1.4 (platform restrictions).

It uses a lot of complex data types.
There is a particular method that receives a complex object and returns the same object type (possibly modified).

The serialization works ok, but the deserialization is not working.
The "atributos" tag is causing the error.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to use the same registered data type for both ways or at least a better way than doying that by hand (I'll have to do for a lot of methods)?

Sorry for the long long long message. But I had to include everything related to that.
Sorry for the sloppy code. This is just a test.

Thanks very much.

Here is the request XML:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header/>
    <v:Body>
        <iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicket xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
            <ticketAutenticacao>4FSejSSb5JY8N5Sy+nwYDOxNaBsPhFuyF9Dsws8AiNQvwN0nGOUP8w==</ticketAutenticacao>
            <idProcesso>10074</idProcesso>
            <parametrosIniciais>
                <n0:KeyValue xmlns:n0="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT">
                    <n0:key>pnNome</n0:key>
                    <n0:value i:type="d:string">Person1</n0:value>
                </n0:KeyValue>
                <n1:KeyValue xmlns:n1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT">
                    <n1:key>pnNumero</n1:key>
                    <n1:value i:type="d:string">7001832700</n1:value>
                </n1:KeyValue>
                <n2:KeyValue xmlns:n2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT">
                    <n2:key>pnTipoSAP</n2:key>
                    <n2:value i:type="d:string">Z005</n2:value>
                </n2:KeyValue>
                <n3:KeyValue xmlns:n3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT">
                    <n3:key>CodCanal</n3:key>
                    <n3:value i:type="d:string">5</n3:value>
                </n3:KeyValue>
            </parametrosIniciais>
        </iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicket>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

Here is the answer XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:atributos>
                    <a:KeyValue>
                        <a:key>pnNome</a:key>
                        <a:value xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">Person 1</a:value>
                    </a:KeyValue>
                    <a:KeyValue>
                        <a:key>pnNumero</a:key>
                        <a:value xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">7001832700</a:value>
                    </a:KeyValue>
                    <a:KeyValue>
                        <a:key>pnTipoSAP</a:key>
                        <a:value xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">Z005</a:value>
                    </a:KeyValue>
                    <a:KeyValue>
                        <a:key>CodCanal</a:key>
                        <a:value xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string">5</a:value>
                    </a:KeyValue>
                </a:atributos>
                <a:dominio>0</a:dominio>
                <a:ds xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.DTO" i:nil="true"/>
                <a:idInstanciaProcesso>66806</a:idInstanciaProcesso>
                <a:idProcesso>10074</a:idProcesso>
                <a:instanciaEmExecucao xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.DTO" i:nil="true"/>
                <a:nomeUsuario>7001832700</a:nomeUsuario>
                <a:revisao>15076</a:revisao>
                <a:statusInstanciaProcesso>NaoIniciado</a:statusInstanciaProcesso>
            </iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResult>
        </iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is the exception:

```
Unknown Property: KeyValue
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown Property: KeyValue
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readSerializable(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readSerializable(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readSerializable(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Unknown Source)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(Unknown Source)
 at ServicoSegundaVia.iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicket(ServicoSegundaVia.java:194)
 at ServicoSegundaVia.main(ServicoSegundaVia.java:25)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ServicoSegundaVia.main(ServicoSegundaVia.java:30)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
// Calling code
public static DadosInstanciaProcessoDTO iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicket(){
    //Get Ticket
    String ticket = "XYZ"; // Got from somewhere else

    //Conect on Service.......
    String sNAMESPACE   = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String sMETHOD_NAME = "iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicket";
    String sURL         = "http://192.168.0.197:88/WFPExecutorService.svc";
    String sSOAPAACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IWFPExecutorService/iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicket";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(sNAMESPACE, sMETHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty("ticketAutenticacao", ticket);
    request.addProperty("idProcesso", "10074");

    ParametrosIniciais parIni = new ParametrosIniciais();
    parIni.add(new KeyValue("pnNome", "Person 1"));
    parIni.add(new KeyValue("pnNumero","7001832700"));
    parIni.add(new KeyValue("pnTipoSAP","Z005"));
    parIni.add(new KeyValue("CodCanal","5"));

    PropertyInfo info = new PropertyInfo();
    info.name = "parametrosIniciais";
    info.type = ParametrosIniciais.class;
    request.addProperty(info, parIni);

    //ENVELOPE
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    envelope.addMapping(sNAMESPACE, "iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResponse", IniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResponse.class);        
    envelope.addMapping(sNAMESPACE, "iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResult", DadosInstanciaProcessoDTO.class);        
    envelope.addMapping("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT", "atributos", Atributos.class);        
    envelope.addMapping("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT", "KeyValue", KeyValue.class);        

    //Creates a conection, using a String URL..
    HttpTransportSE myHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(sURL);
    myHttpTransport.debug = true;

    try {
        myHttpTransport.call(sSOAPAACTION, envelope);
        IniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResponse response = (IniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResponse)envelope.bodyIn;
        DadosInstanciaProcessoDTO dto = response.getDadosIniExecProc();
        System.out.println(dto.getAtributo("pnNome"));
        return dto;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Data Types:

```
package data;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class Atributos extends Vector implements KvmSerializable {

    public Object getProperty(int i) { return this.get(i); }

    public int getPropertyCount() { return this.size(); }

    public void setProperty(int i, Object o) { this.add(o); }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo pi) {
        pi.name = "KeyValue";
        pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT";
        pi.type = KeyValue.class;
    }
}
```

--

```
package data;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class DadosExecucaoDTO  implements KvmSerializable {

    private Atributos atributos = null;
    private String sDominio = "";
    private Object oDs = null;
    private String sIdInstanciaProcesso = "";
    private String sIdProcesso = "";
    private Object oInstanciaEmExecucao = null;
    private String sNomeUsuario = "";
    private String sRevisao = "";
    private String sStatusInstanciaProcesso = "";

    public Object getProperty(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0: return atributos;
            case 1: return sDominio;
            case 2: return oDs;
            case 3: return sIdInstanciaProcesso;                
            case 4: return sIdProcesso;
            case 5: return oInstanciaEmExecucao;
            case 6: return sNomeUsuario;
            case 7: return sRevisao;
            case 8: return sStatusInstanciaProcesso;
        }
        return null;    
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 9;
    }

    public void setProperty(int i, Object o) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0: this.atributos = (Atributos)o; break;
            case 1: this.sDominio = o.toString(); break;                
            case 2: this.oDs = o; break;
            case 3: this.sIdInstanciaProcesso = o.toString(); break;                
            case 4: this.sIdProcesso = o.toString(); break;
            case 5: this.oInstanciaEmExecucao = o; break;
            case 6: this.sNomeUsuario = o.toString(); break;
            case 7: this.sRevisao = o.toString(); break;                
            case 8: this.sStatusInstanciaProcesso = o.toString(); break;                 
        }           
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int i, Hashtable hshtbl, PropertyInfo pi) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                pi.name = "atributos"; pi.type = Atributos.class;
                pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT";
                break;
            case 1:
                pi.name = "dominio"; pi.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT";
                break; 
            case 2:
                pi.name = "ds"; pi.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS;
                pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.DTO";
                break;                 
            case 3:
                pi.name = "idInstanciaProcesso"; pi.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT";
                break; 
            case 4:
                pi.name = "idProcesso"; pi.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT";
                break; 
            case 5:
                pi.name = "instanciaEmExecucao"; pi.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS;
                pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.DTO";
                break; 
            case 6:
                pi.name = "nomeUsuario"; pi.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT";
                break;             
            case 7:
                pi.name = "revisao"; pi.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT";
                break; 
            case 8:
                pi.name = "statusInstanciaProcesso"; pi.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT";
                break; 
        }        
    }
}
```

--

```
package data;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class IniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResponse implements KvmSerializable {
    private DadosInstanciaProcessoDTO iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResult;

    public DadosInstanciaProcessoDTO getDadosIniExecProc() {
        return iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResult;
    }

    public Object getProperty(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0: return iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResult;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public void setProperty(int i, Object o) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0: this.iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResult = (DadosInstanciaProcessoDTO)o; break;
        }
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable hshtbl, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                info.type = DadosInstanciaProcessoDTO.class;
                info.name = "iniciarExecucaoProcessoComTicketResult";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
package data;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class KeyValue implements KvmSerializable {

    private String sKey = "";
    private String sValue = "";

    public KeyValue(String k, String v){
        this.sKey = k; this.sValue = v;
    }

    public Object getProperty(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0: return sKey;
            case 1: return sValue;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public void setProperty(int i, Object o) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0: this.sKey = o.toString(); break;
            case 1: this.sValue = o.toString(); break;                
        }       
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int i, Hashtable hshtbl, PropertyInfo pi) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                pi.name = "key"; pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT";
                pi.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 1:
                pi.name = "value"; pi.namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyWS.WS.EXT";
                pi.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS;
                break;                
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the solution? I'm facing the same problem right now :(

Answer (score 1):

You must add the getters and setters to all the classes that implement `KvmSerializable`.

Comment: Nothing has changed.
It seems the problem is related to maaping when the namespace is not defined in the tag itself. Altough I'm not sure.